# Paginate from model method data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I start with CakePHP framework. I want use paginator on my site but I wanted to do all the operations in the model.

When I use all in controller is OK:

```
public function index() {
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('MyModel');
        $this->set('data', $data);
    }
```

but when i want use method from model have problem with column: MyModel:

```
public function index() {
    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->MyModel->getData());
    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

//model method

```
public function getData()
    {
        $data = $this->find('all');
        return $data;
    }
```

ofc when I display this method without paginate is ok:

```
public function index() {
    $data = $this->MyModel->getData();
    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

Comment: `$this->Paginator->paginate($this->MyModel->getData());` Where did you come up with the idea that you can make returned data paginatable? The paginate() method expects, as documented, a string (the model name to be exact).

Comment: OK, but how use my own function from model and paginate? I dont want get data from DB in controller. I think its bad idea. All operations on DB should be in the model.

Comment: You misunderstand the concept. The data is always outside of the controller until fetched via paginate() call. Thus it makes no difference. Just stick to the first way - that obviously worked. There are bigger fish to fry :)

Comment: OK :) When I create a simple search engine with pagination I must create this without model method?

Answer (score 1):

Friend you are trying to apply the pagination on the "array" not on the model. Cakephp provide the functionality to pagination data for the model instance. As the model data transaction method have the database connection object and the pagination component manage that object.